# Логические операторы в return

Tags: javascript, return

Расскажите, пожалуйста, про логику в return (или подскажите где искать). Я не раз натыкался на на код типа

```
return a || b;
return a >= 0;
```

Comment: Не очень понятно что вам непонятно. `let tmp = a || b; return tmp;` — так понятнее?

Comment: @AlexeyTen может речь про | |  и про >= ?

Comment: https://javascript.ru/boolean-operators
 https://javascript.ru/comparison-operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это два разных случаях. В первом варианте вернется значение переменной a или b, а во втором булевое значение выражения a >= b.
Рассмотрим оба варианта поподробнее

```js
function example(a, b){
  // Если a не нулевое значение(false, 0, '', undefined, null, NaN), то вернет значение переменной а
  // В противном случае вернет значение переменной b 
  return a || b
}

// Вернет 5, так как первое значение нулевое
var ex1 = example(null, 5)
console.log(ex1)

// Вернет "Пример" так как первое значение не нулевое

var ex2 = example("Пример", 5)
console.log(ex2)

function isMoreOrEqual(a, b){
  // Всегда будет возвращать булевое значение true или false в зависимости от истинности выражение
  return a >= b
}

// Вернет false, так как 5 не больше или равно 6
var ex3 = isMoreOrEqual(5, 6)
console.log(ex3)

// Вернет true, так как 6 больше или равно 5
var ex4 = isMoreOrEqual(6, 5)
console.log(ex4)
```